# FCM http v1 API integration for servers using programming languages including c++ that does not have SDK supports

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We're considering to migrate legacy API to [FCM HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) to fully utilize FCM functionalities.

Although they provide [API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) for various programming languages, it could not be possible to cover all programming languages including C++.

Because our push server is written in C++, we decided to implement the protocols. However, we could not find any documents on how to get access token using service-account.json file or server key that can be found in firebase console.

Is there anyone who integrated FCM HTTP v1 API without SDKs that FCM provides?

Comment: Any solution yet in this topic?

Comment: These articles helped me to implement the protocol in C++. Now it works well.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Comment: @jwchoi, kudos to you sir! That was very helpful. Unfortunately this info is so hard to find in this heap of doc pages of Google. I think you should make this comment an answer to your original question and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.

These articles helped me to implement the protocol in C++. Now it works well. developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account